# How to Sort List based on custom Date Dart

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, datetime, dart

I have the following function that sort List based on Date but if DateTime before firstDay of month it create double list

what I want is it sort list based on first day of month and remove all item before firstday

```
List expenseData= [

 {id: 1242, detail: milk, amount: $5, date: 2021-06-21 00:00:00:000},
 {id: 1242, detail: egg, amount: $2, date: 2021-05-15 00:00:00:000},
 {id: 1243, detail: bread, amount: $3, date: 2021-05-13 00:00:00:000},
 {id: 1244, detail: butter, amount: $7, date: 2021-05-22 00:00:00:000},
 {id: 1247, detail: butter, amount: $7, date: 2021-06-10 00:00:00:000},

];

pieDatathisMonth() {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    var firstDayMonth = DateTime(now.year, now.month, 1);
    var sortExpData = expenseData;
    sortExpData.sort((d1, d2) {
      return d1.date.compareTo(firstDayMonth);
    });
    sortExpData.toList();
    thisMonthExpense.addAll(sortExpData);
    update();
  }
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Your `sort` callback is wrong.  It *must* compare `d1` to `d2`, not `d1` to some other date.  Otherwise `sort()` cannot properly order `d1` relative to `d2`.   If you want to remove all dates before a cut-off date, it'd be better to filter your list with `expenseData.where((dateTime) => dateTime.compareTo(firstDayOfMonth) >= 0)` and *then* sort it.

Comment: nothing error showed because the problem is my filtering 

I see it 
thanks for your clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix to your sort method. I've made some `DateTime` cast because my `expenseData` is formatted as `Map<String, dynamic>`.

```dart
void pieDatathisMonth() {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var firstDayMonth = DateTime(now.year, now.month, 1);
  var sortExpData = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(expenseData);
  
  // remove all data before firstday because you don't need to sort them.
  sortExpData.removeWhere((e) => (e['date'] as DateTime).isBefore(firstDayMonth));
  
  sortExpData.sort((d1, d2) {
    return (d1['date'] as DateTime).compareTo(d2['date'] as DateTime);
  });
  sortExpData.toList();
  thisMonthExpense.addAll(sortExpData);
  update();
}
```